# DNA of Different Species and The Fossil Record of Their Common Ancestor

Tags: evolution, dna, fossil

Let me please be clear about something. I believe in evolution. The evidence and data are compelling and conclusive which makes it a very well-established theory.

I'm seeking a certain evidence (if it's existent) for evolution.

Assume we have two species (species A and species B) and we have full information of their genomes. I believe, by using their genomes, we can deduce when their most recent common ancestor lived (let's say X years ago). 
Are their any instances in which this X number (which was produced mathematically) matched the age of some fossil (say species C) which has similar attributes to species A and species B? Any data about the ancient DNA of species C which may reinforce the evidence? Do we have something for humans and chimps?

I'm seeking a gourp of, arguably, unrelated quantitative data that point remarkably and decisively to common ancestor/evolution.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could explain discrepancies between dates provided by the fossil record vs. the molecular clock?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/76786/what-could-explain-discrepancies-between-dates-provided-by-the-fossil-record-vs)

Comment: One difficulty is that, even if a reliable molecular clock existed to predict when two species diverged, and if a fossil were found that seemed to match the phenotypic profile of a common ancestor, it would not be possible to conclude with certainty that it really is the common ancestor unless the fossil also provided DNA that could be compared to that of the two modern species.  It might be possible to find more modern examples though, for example by comparing the DNA of mummified Egyptian cats to that of modern cats.